# Algorithm to create a tree structure using excel sheet

Tags: php, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

I have faced a problem when creating a tree structure using following excel sheet.

[image]

I wanted to store those cell elements as categories. There are many to many relationship between each categories. That means each parent category has many child categories and also each child category has many parent categories.

[image]

I'm going to use PHP as language but it is not important.

If there anyone who had this kind of experience or any idea to traverse and store categories as a tree(parent child relationship), it will be very helpful for me.

//==============Update===================

Number of columns may be different. That means there are number of excel files and their headings' count and heading name may be different. Therefore I need to find common solution for all sheets.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear now what is your question. Just asking for general tips is too broad. Please clarify it.

Comment: From the screenshot it's unclear why description says each child has many parents, it looks like there's only one parent for each child (tree). Can you explain?

Comment: @user3964075 its for sharing purpose. Please ignore for now. We can say it is one to many relationship for now.

Comment: @Mate juhasz I couldn't identy parent child when traversing categories(cell data). Its complecated when one parent has many childs.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

1. When iterating cell items in first row, calculate the count of
   columns.
2. Create variables for each columns dynamically using column count. It is only for first row of the sheet.

   ```
   if($row->getRowIndex()==1){
     //Create category variables
     for($cat_var_count =1; $cat_var_count < $i; $cat_var_count++){
        ${$category_header."_".$cat_var_count} = "";
     }
   }
   ```
3. Store each cell data in relevant variable

   ${$category_header."_".$i} = $last_inserted_row_category_id;
4. Check whether cell data is empty or not
5. Add data items to category table
6. Only update relevant variable for each column if it is not empty
7. Get parent variable data by decrementing current cell element number by one. That is previous cell data. Don't update relevant variable if column data is empty.

   ```
   $model_cat_parent->parent_id = ${$category_header."_".($i-1)};
   $model_cat_parent->child_id = $last_inserted_row_category_id;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Begin by creating fully populated table like:

[image]

Then select cell **A2** and apply *Conditional formatting* to make the cell "invisible" if it has the same value as the cell above:

[image]

and copy they format both down and across.

[image]

You now have the visual effect you desire and can process the table with standard Excel functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I'm looking for an algorithm to travers excel sheet as a tree.

Comment: @cha  It **is** a representation of a tree.  For each *terminal node*, it defines the nodes *parent, grandparent*, etc.

Comment: Yes. But I want them to populate in the database. Problem is traversing data and populate them as parent child categories.

Comment: @cha  **Access** may be a better tool for you.